# Ml-kit did not detecting small QR-code why?

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I want to scan small QR-code(1cm x 1cm) I am trying to scan by Using [this same code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit). It's detecting the large size qr-code perfectly but not detecting the small size qr-code. Is there have any way by which I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The smartphone camera has to read each and every data module to be able to decode a QR Code And you know that quality of the camera varies widely across different smartphones. Some of them are very good and can scan even very small QR Codes. But others simply can’t so try with some other device to check you have issue in code or with device